# Bash Parameter Expansion - match up to but not including regex

Tags: regex, bash, variable-expansion

I want to match up to but not including a given **string**. So in a text like

```
seirots-llet-ew-yhw-20-30-seirotS lleT eW yhW - yrotS ruoY lleT
```

I want it to be reduced to

```
20-30-seirotS lleT eW yhW - yrotS ruoY lleT
```

So I have a set of reversed strings which I capture in a bash variable and want to expand the variable with a regex to achieve something like this below:

Input:

```
seirots-llet-ew-yhw-20-30-seirotS lleT eW yhW - yrotS ruoY lleT
spets-ruoy-ecarter-30-30-spetS ruoY ecarteR - yrotS ruoY lleT
cra-yrots-40-30-crA yrotS ruoY - yrotS ruoY lleT
skcabhsalf-etaerc-50-30-skcabhsalF gnitaerC - yrotS ruoY lleT
noitnetta-60-30-noitnettA gnipeeK dna gnitteG - yrotS ruoY lleT
```

Output:

```
20-30-seirotS lleT eW yhW - yrotS ruoY lleT
30-30-spetS ruoY ecarteR - yrotS ruoY lleT
40-30-crA yrotS ruoY - yrotS ruoY lleT
50-30-skcabhsalF gnitaerC - yrotS ruoY lleT
60-30-noitnettA gnipeeK dna gnitteG - yrotS ruoY lleT
```

My bash code is as follows:

```
value="${reversed##*[a-z]-[0-9]}"
```

But the result is **not** what I desire:

```
0-30-seirotS lleT eW yhW - yrotS ruoY lleT
0-30-spetS ruoY ecarteR - yrotS ruoY lleT
0-30-crA yrotS ruoY - yrotS ruoY lleT
0-30-skcabhsalF gnitaerC - yrotS ruoY lleT
0-30-noitnettA gnipeeK dna gnitteG - yrotS ruoY lleT
```

Notice how the first **digit** is omitted.

Comment: I'm not getting what you're asking like _at all_. And please post text snippets not images. 1.1k rep you should know that.

Comment: is this what you want? `s='seirots-llet-ew-yhw-20-30'; echo "${s%%[0-9]*}"`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I added text

Comment: @Sundeep dude! I want the exact opposite! How?

Comment: exact opposite: `s='seirots-llet-ew-yhw-20-30'; echo "${s#${s%%[0-9]*}}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove everything after first matching digit:

```
$ s='seirots-llet-ew-yhw-20-30-seirotS lleT eW yhW - yrotS ruoY lleT'
$ echo "${s%%[0-9]*}"
seirots-llet-ew-yhw-
```

So, in above case, `20-30-seirotS lleT eW yhW - yrotS ruoY lleT` was matched to be removed and resulting string is `seirots-llet-ew-yhw-`. The result can be then used to as string to be removed from beginning of `s` variable

```
$ echo "${s#${s%%[0-9]*}}"
20-30-seirotS lleT eW yhW - yrotS ruoY lleT
```

If `extglob` shell option is available - see [pattern matching manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html)

```
$ echo "${s##+([!0-9])}"
20-30-seirotS lleT eW yhW - yrotS ruoY lleT
```

`+([!0-9])` means one or more non-digit characters

With regex matching:

```
$ [[ $s =~ [0-9].* ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
20-30-seirotS lleT eW yhW - yrotS ruoY lleT
```